# How to make a back button that goes to the parent page in C# Razor and 2sxc App?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a 2sxc app that is a simple parent-and-child setup. So there's a listing of cards and each card has a details view. I use this app on 6 pages - each with their own unique content. I want to make a "back" link inside of the details view that goes back to that detail's parent.

So one of the pages is called "Motivate", and I want it so if a user goes to "Motivate" and then clicks on one of the details views, let's say "motivate/details/marketer", I want a back link on that details view that goes back to the "Motivate" page. But this link would have to work for each of the 6 categories dynamically. How would I create this in c# razor?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code just so that I can see how its all done?

You can the current page id in 2sxc using "@Dnn.Tab.TabID"

If you can get the parent page ID you can use the following link to go to that page

"http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?tabid=TABID"

Regards

Kieran

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this. Here's my code:

```
<a href="@Dnn.Tab.FullUrl">Go back</a>
```

This works because when I'm on the details view (a different template), the landing page is still the Tab's Full URL.